# i can' t understand why 15 0 then 20 appears

Tags: java

This is the code I can't understand why v.i take 20! The result of this code is:

```
15 0
20
```

Code:

```
class Value {
   public int i = 15;
}

class tes {
   public static void main(String argv[]) {
      tes t = new tes();
      t.first();
   }

   public void first() /* methode first */
   {
      int i = 5;
      Value v = new Value(); /* appel au classe Value */
      v.i = 25;
      second(v, i);
      System.out.println(v.i);
   } /* here it appears 20 ????? */

   public void second(Value v, int i) {
      i = 0;
      v.i = 20;
      Value val = new Value();
      v = val;
      System.out.println(v.i + " " + i);
   }
} /* it appears 15 0 i understand this */
```

Comment: If you are going to post code, please take the time and effort to format it well.

Comment: I've just now formatted it for you, but in the future, please do this yourself.

Comment: Go through the code in a debugger and follow the assignments..

Comment: Duplicate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748996/java-object-reference-is-changed-in-a-method-and-understanding-the-result?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

It's because in Java you pass a reference to an object by value. You can't change where this reference points to. You think you are changing what external `v` from `first()` points to inside of `second()`, but that's not the case. Effectively in the function signature of `second()` you are just declaring a variable `v` which initially points to passed value. You are changing that variable, not the external reference.

However when you assign to `v.i` it does have effect and updates its value. 20 is a correct result.

Make all arguments `final`, compile and look at the errors. This will provide a good insight.

This might explain it better than me: [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference).

Answer (score 0):

Step through your code carefully:

```
v.i = 20;  //Okay, pretty straightforward
```

Then you call:

```
Value val = new Value();  //Think about what val.i is
```

Now when you call this, `v` is pointing at the same object that `val` is pointing at:

```
v = val;
```

What's the value of `i` in that object?

Answer (score 0):

v=val v is only a reference of val, not the original v.

```
v-->i=25
```

Then in method second

```
v-->i=20

Value val = new Value();
```

allocate a new memory space for val

now

```
v-->val.i = 15
```

after this, you can modify v.i as much as you want without affect the original data stored in v.i .